# React Mongodb Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, post, localhost

I am trying with a browser extension application with react and mongodb. The `POST` operation is:

```
 create(urls){
    console.log(urls);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/url', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(urls),
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(json => resolve(json))
        .catch(err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

The problem is, sometimes data are sent perfectly. But most of the time I am getting this weird error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I am also getting a similar error when I refresh my extension application in
`chrome://extensions/` which is:

```
POST chrome-extension://my_ext_id/url net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I think the error has something to do with the `http://localhost:3001/url`.

I have given the permissions like this:

```
 "permissions": ["alarms", "tabs", "http://localhost:3001/url"],
```

But it seems it is not working as I hoped.

Any help will be appreciated.